# What to do if pyinstaller can't find dynamic or custom libraries?

Tags: python, compilation, libraries, pyinstaller

I'm trying to use pyinstaller to create an single exe file of my Python program, but when the process completes, the exe can't be run. After reviewing the console output from the process, I can see that following the line:

126946 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries

I get several hundred lines of "WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-**any number of different .dll** dependency of **path to where the dll or pyd is saved**

I installed Python using a default configuration and have always installed Python packages using pip. Pyinstaller is supposed to be straight-forward and not need a lot of extra steps, like creating a setup.py file, but it seems something is missing which tells pyinstaller where to look for those missing libraries. Is there a workaround for this? Or even a better python to exe compiler that I should use?

EDIT:
To provide more info - My program is made up of 5 modules, and among those I use three 3rd party packages including: PyQt5, pandas and ArcGIS. Additionally, I have two sql files that are part of the program as well. I have a feeling that pyinstaller can only compile simple scripts and by using other packages, modules and external files, it just it's made to handle that kind of stuff.

Comment: can you show us the command you used to create single exe

Comment: Initially, I just entered pyinstaller myFile.py into the console, while in the directory of myFile.py. Since I wanted to just have a self contained exe, I changed it to: pyinstaller --onedir --name=myFile --windowed --onefile --noconsole myFile.py

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PyInstaller on mac can't find libpython2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38920076/pyinstaller-on-mac-cant-find-libpython2-7)

Comment: @ishandutta2007 That looks like an entirely different issue, since the error message references a different missing library and problem.

Comment: @NLee23 `libpython2.7.dylib` dylib stands for dynamic library. In both case library is present and is in appropiate path but the code is not able to access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a series of changes which resulted in the build compiling and running correctly.

First, pyinstaller is missing a 'hook' file for pandas, so one must be manually created. For me the hook folder was located here: "C:\Users\natha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks"

Inside that folder I created a file named hook-pandas.py and the only contents of that file was one line: hiddenimports = ['pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas']

I did install the Windows 10 SDK, but I'm not sure if that was just part of the problem, or what it affected if anything. My program was made up of multiple modules, because I like to separate different types of processes in different files. However, to simplify things I combined all my code to one .py file and had just one other file that contained my PyQt5/Qt Designer auto-generated GUI code. I removed all imports that read like

```
from x.y import z
```

I received errors in a few builds where it seemed like pyinstaller didn't recognize those things. So I kept things very straight-forward, like

```
import PyQt5
```

Lastly, when I went to compile the build, using the -p command, I added two file paths; one pointed to the root location of my program, which is where the other module(the PyQt5 module) was saved and the second path was to "C:\Users\natha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages". Once these things are in place, compile completed normally and the build runs perfectly. So in summary, the keys to success here are:

-Ensure there is a hook-pandas.py file IF pandas is being used in your script
-Ensure the hook-pandas.py file contains this line:

```
hiddenimports = ['pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas']
```

-And be sure -p command is used to direct pyinstaller to where your custom modules and any python packages are saved. My -p command read like this:

```
-p C:\Users\natha\Desktop\Python_Projects\CompEval\code:C:\Users\natha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages
```

Notice the colon separating the two paths.

I think those are the main things to check for and secondary things would be the

```
from x.y import z
```

type imports, to avoid those.

Answer (score 1):

funny that someone asked a similar question ~44mins ago but using python with excel.

Anyway, hope this answer here works and the auditor/moderator doesn't freak out about it ;p

I've copied the instructions from the my recommended solution and used the link as supplementary. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OZSZHmWSOeM

### **Py to exe Project**

**Prerequisites**

Python : Python 2.7 or Python 3.3+ (basically anything that pyinstaller runs on)

Chrome : to run the user interface

**Installing**

Download the zipped folder

Open cmd/terminal and `cd` to unzipped folder (recommend putting it on your desktop for now)

Execute `pip install -r requirements.txt`

**Running the Application**

Run `run.py`. Chrome will open in app mode with the project running inside.

**Using the Application**

Select your script location (paste in or use the file explorer)

Address-box outline will become blue when file exists

Select other options and add things like an icon or other files

Click the big blue button at the bottom to convert

Find your converted files in [unzipped folder]/output when completed

**Passing the File With Arguments**

Alternatively you can execute python `run.py [filename]`. This will open up the window with the filename in the script location.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I gave this a shot, but it either creates a build that doesn't run or locks up in the compiling process. I think the problem is related to Pandas. A PyQt5 folder gets created (if the compiling finishes), but a Pandas file doesn't. Also, in the pyinstaller\hooks folder, there wasn't a pandas file, so I had come across another post on how to create one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the Windows 10 SDK and then update your Path to include the ucrt dlls, which may be found here post-installation:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Redist\ucrt\DLLs\x86

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That may be part of the issue, but after installing the SDK, it still won't compile properly. There must still be another step that has to be done.

Comment: Another question on this - after downloading the SDK, should I have done something different when compiling? Something that would point pyinstaller to these drivers that it seems to be looking for? I checked and the dlls that come up in the WARNING while compiling are clearly in the folder you reference above. So, they exist, but pyinstaller doesn't see them, or it would seem. Any other suggestions? Thanks again for your time.

Comment: Did you add the directory to your path as I mentioned in the answer? Double check by echo-ing it before you run the pyinstaller command.

Comment: I did add it to the path but I did not tell pyinstaller to look in that folder. However, I can try that the next time I compile and see what it changes. I was able to compile regardless, so these particular drivers may not directly affect my program.